# print sum of 2 dictionary values based on key

Tags: python, dictionary

My code looks like:

```
{'Bug Out Bag': ['q', 0.25, 100], 'XM': ['q', 0.25, 10]}

print('{}'.format(float(addition1)+float(addition2)) )
```

I'm getting an error of :

```
addition1 = coins_in_the_bag[0]
KeyError: 0
```

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have the key `0` in your dictionary.  You have "Bug Out Bag" and "XM".  Also you're not showing all your code so it's a little hard to see what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think what you want is something like: `sum(v[2] for v in coins_in_the_bag.values())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
coins_in_the_bag = {'Bug Out Bag': ['q', 0.25, 100], 'XM': ['q', 0.25, 10]}
```

`coins_in_the_bag` is a `dict`. Its contents are accessed using keys such as

```
>>> coins_in_the_bag['Bug Out Bag']
# ['q', 0.25, 100]
>>> coins_in_the_bag['XM']
# ['q', 0.25, 10]
```

Also, `coins_in_the_bag['Bug Out Bag']` would return a list. Be alert to call `float` on a number, and not the whole list